# Which is the best Open Source JavaScript Mobile Framework involving charts?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, blackberry, cross-platform

I am going to develop a mobile application which will involves lots of Bar & Pie Charts. So which is the best efficient framework for this very Purpose.

Comment: I only know the second best :(

Comment: Best in sense like which will be lightweight,persistent and contains most of native API's of mobile platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Sencha touch charts](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch-charts-1.0.0/examples/). It provides nice looking customizable bar charts and Pie charts for mobile applications.